# Using groovy to parse JSON object in shell scripts for Jenkin

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

Say I have a JSON as following:

```
{"id":"1.0.0-6",
"version":"1.0.0",
"build":6,
"tag":"android-v1.0.0-6",
"commitHash":"5a78c4665xxxxxxxxxxe1b62c682f84",
"dateCreated":"2020-03-02T08:11:29.912Z"}
```

I want to take out the version id from it in Jenkins Groovy file and pass the version id to a JIRA Plugin called XRAY so that it will create a build version as Label in JIRA.

```
stage('Get App version') {
      steps {
          container('devicefarm') {
               steps {
                   sh "LATEST_VERSION=$(curl ${APP_ARTIFACTORY_URL}/${XRAY_PLATFORM}/builds/latest.json | sed \"s/.*$VERSION_KEY\":\"\\([^\"]*\\).*/'\\1'/\")"
               }
           }
      }
}
environment {
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION = 'uk-xxx'
        XRAY_ENVIRONMENT = 'e2e'
        VERSION_KEY = 'id'
        XRAY_PLATFORM = 'Android'
        APP_ARTIFACTORY_URL = 'https://artifactory.example.com/mobile'
        LATEST_VERSION = ''
}
```

I have two questions, will the result of curl command been assigned to variable defined in the same Jenkins file called 'LATEST_VERSION' as expected?

I probably can test it by running the pipe line on Jenkins but I got another issue that prevent me from doing this, it complains that 'Identifier or code block expected'.

[image: error while include sh bash in groovy Jenkins file]

While running same in a sh file, it doesn't have this issue, version id was retrieved from JSON as expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few steps to achieving this. First, we need to fix your shell method execution. We will convert it into a valid shell execution that returns the standard out of the execution and assigns it to a variable:

```
build_json = sh(label: 'Retrieve Build Info', script: "curl ${APP_ARTIFACTORY_URL}/${XRAY_PLATFORM}/builds/latest.json", returnStdout: true)
```

This is a valid shell method execution that will also return the standard out and assign it to a variable. See the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#sh-shell-script) for more information.

Next, we need to parse the resulting JSON, and assign that return value to a variable:

```
build_map = readJSON(text: build_json)
```

See the [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readjson-read-json-from-files-in-the-workspace) for more information.

Finally, we now have a Map where we can access the value for the `latest_version` key and assign it to a variable. We can access with this syntax:

```
latest_version = build_map['version']
```

or this:

```
latest_version = build_map.version
```

Note that while this does answer your question, you cannot pass dynamic values to an `environment` block during the pipeline execution (which your question implies you want to perform later). So, you are going to need try a different route for that, and may need to ask a followup question about it.

Comment: thanks a lot indeed. Really helpful for those tips, save me hours

Comment: please could you take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61658578/how-to-pass-dynamic-values-to-an-environment-block-during-the-pipeline-execution

Comment: This works too `XRAY_LATEST_VERSION = sh(script: 'curl -s ${APP_ARTIFACTORY_URL}/${XRAY_PLATFORM}/builds/latest.json | jq .version | sed \'s/"//g\'', returnStdout: true).trim()`.